# str_replace failing with specific characters

Tags: php, regex, xpath

Running a simple str_replace that seems to have sound parts, but when I run the str_replace with these parts, the output is incorrect.

```
foreach($x->query("//img") as $node) 
{   
    $absoluteImage = make_absolute($node->getAttribute("src"), $url);
    $iterateImage = str_replace($node->getAttribute("src"), $absoluteImage, $html);   
}

function make_absolute($url, $base) { 

    // Return base if no url
    if( ! $url) return $base;

    // Already absolute URL
    if(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_SCHEME) != '') return $url;

    // Only containing query or anchor
    if($url[0] == '#' || $url[0] == '?') return $base.$url;

    // Parse base URL and convert to local variables: $scheme, $host, $path
    extract(parse_url($base));

    // If no path, use /
    if( ! isset($path)) $path = '/';

    // Remove non-directory element from path
    $path = preg_replace('#/[^/]*$#', '', $path);

    // Destroy path if relative url points to root
    if($url[0] == '/') $path = '';

    // Dirty absolute URL
    $abs = "$host$path/$url";

    // Replace '//' or '/./' or '/foo/../' with '/'
    $re = array('#(/\.?/)#', '#/(?!\.\.)[^/]+/\.\./#');
    for($n = 1; $n > 0; $abs = preg_replace($re, '/', $abs, -1, $n)) {}

    // Absolute URL is ready!
    return $scheme.'://'.$abs;
}
```

The code is for a scraper that replaces the src portion of img tag from a relative to absolute URL. make_absolute is the function that does the work, and it works fine. When I echo out both $absoluteImage and $node->getAttribute("src") they both print the correct result. The absolute URL, and relative URL respectively. But when I run the str_replace function with these two parts, the result is incorrect. See the below data:

The relative URL's:

```
<img border="0" src="media/splash/a1.jpg" width="123" height="49">
<img border="0" src="media/splash/a2.jpg" width="136" height="49">
<img border="0" src="media/splash/pixel_clear.gif" width="187" height="1"><br>
<img border="0" src="media/splash/b1.jpg" width="123" height="66">
<img border="0" src="media/splash/b2.jpg" width="136" height="66">
<img border="0" src="media/splash/b3.jpg" width="187" height="66">
<img border="0" src="media/splash/c1.jpg" width="123" height="150">
<img border="0" src="media/splash/c2.jpg" width="136" height="150">
<img border="0" src="media/splash/c3.jpg" width="187" height="150">
<img border="0" src="media/splash/pixel_clear.gif" width="123" height="1">
<img border="0" src="media/splash/d1.jpg" width="136" height="127">
<img border="0" src="media/splash/d2.jpg" width="187" height="127">
<img border="0" src="media/splash/pixel_clear.gif" width="446" height="59">
<img border="0" src="media/splash/f1.jpg" width="446" height="147"><br>
<img border="0" src="media/splash/g1.jpg" width="446" height="142"></td>
```

The resulting absolute URL's:

```
<img border="0" src="http://www.bjnormand.com/media/splash/a1.jpg" width="123" height="49">
<img border="0" src="http://www.bjnormand.com/media/splash/a2.jpg" width="136" height="49">
<img border="0" src="http://www.bjnormand.com/http://www.bjnormand.com/http://www.bjnormand.com/media/splash/pixel_clear.gif" width="187" height="1"><br>
<img border="0" src="http://www.bjnormand.com/media/splash/b1.jpg" width="123" height="66">
<img border="0" src="http://www.bjnormand.com/media/splash/b2.jpg" width="136" height="66">
<img border="0" src="http://www.bjnormand.com/media/splash/b3.jpg" width="187" height="66">
<img border="0" src="http://www.bjnormand.com/media/splash/c1.jpg" width="123" height="150">
<img border="0" src="http://www.bjnormand.com/media/splash/c2.jpg" width="136" height="150">
<img border="0" src="http://www.bjnormand.com/media/splash/c3.jpg" width="187" height="150">
<img border="0" src="http://www.bjnormand.com/http://www.bjnormand.com/http://www.bjnormand.com/media/splash/pixel_clear.gif" width="123" height="1">
<img border="0" src="http://www.bjnormand.com/media/splash/d1.jpg" width="136" height="127">
<img border="0" src="http://www.bjnormand.com/media/splash/d2.jpg" width="187" height="127">
<img border="0" src="http://www.bjnormand.com/http://www.bjnormand.com/http://www.bjnormand.com/media/splash/pixel_clear.gif" width="446" height="59">
<img border="0" src="http://www.bjnormand.com/media/splash/f1.jpg" width="446" height="147"><br>
<img border="0" src="http://www.bjnormand.com/media/splash/g1.jpg" width="446" height="142">
```

The only thing I can see in this is that the 3 lines that are failing have an '_' in the image name.

Anyone have an idea of what's going on?

**UPDATE:**
Tried this to keep tabs on each iteration, but no luck yet:

```
$count = 0;
$imgArr = array();
foreach($x->query("//img") as $node) 
{
    if ($node->getAttribute("src")) {
        $imgArr[] = $node->getAttribute("src");
        $count++;
    }
}
for($i = 0; $i < count($imgArr); $i++) {
    $html = str_replace($imgArr[$i], make_absolute($imgArr[$i], $url), $html);
}

echo $html;
```

Comment: Looks to me like your `make_absolute()` function is generating the incorrect path. Can you post the code for it?

Comment: Sure, see updated code. I've echoed out the two components of the str_replace though, like I mentioned, and they both print out totally accurate.

Comment: I haven't, mainly because I already have the regex for the relative-to-absolute string in the function.. That, and avoiding having to write any unnecessary regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running the string replace on the entire block of HTML every time you go through the loop. Because you have the same image appearing multiple times, it gets replaced every time you hit that same image in the loop.

One solution would be to alter it to include the quotes around the attribute, so that it will only match the complete image name:

```
$iterateImage = str_replace('"'.$node->getAttribute("src").'"', '"'.$absoluteImage.'"', $html);
```

Another option would be to track the images you have done the replace for, and make sure you only do the replace once for each. However if you have one image which has a name which is part of another image name (e.g. `image.jpg` and `myimage.jpg`, you may still have issues.

Comment: Your answer works for this case, but if the src is surrounded by just one or no quotes, it fails. Think it has to be done another way besides str_replace to be a universal solution. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You could try doing a quick regex for any url containing an underscore perhaps:

```
// Dirty absolute URL
$abs = "$host$path/$url";

if (preg_match('/(_)/', $url)) $abs = "$url";
```